# 16:9 padding-bottom trick not working as expected in FireFox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've been trying to implement the responsive 16:9 ratio trick for a content block and while getting the expected result in Chrome, other browsers such as FireFox and Edge display it completely differently and not as intended.

```css
.streamContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background: blue;
}
.streamRatio {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;
  content: '';
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  height: 0;
}
.streamInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="streamContainer">
  <div class="streamRatio">
    <div class="streamInner">
      Content Goes Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following images show the intended result on Chrome and the unintended result on FireFox:

[image: Chrome]
[Chrome - Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGXDv.png)
[image: FireFox]
[FireFox - Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZMt.png)

The blocks of color are just there to help visualise the different boxes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue you have in your example is that the top padding applied to `.streamRatio` is being calculated in relation to the `height` of `.streamContainer` in Firefox but against the `width` of `.streamRatio` in Chrome (giving you the result you expect).

Which one is right? Well, as  it turns out both implementations are correct:

> Percentage margins and paddings on flex items can be resolved against either:
>
> - their own axis (left/right percentages resolve against width,
> - top/bottom resolve against height), or, the inline axis
>     (left/right/top/bottom percentages all resolve against width)
>
> A User Agent must choose one of these two behaviors.

*CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1 ([Flex Item Margins and Paddings](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins))*

For this reason W3C suggests that you don't use percentage based `padding` on flex items.

To fix you will need to remove the flexbox functionality and vertically align the containers using a different method in this case using `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`:

```css
.streamContainer {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
  position: absolute;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  width: 80%;
}
.streamRatio {
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.streamInner {
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="streamContainer">
  <div class="streamRatio">
    <div class="streamInner">
      Content Goes Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and you even explained why! Thank you so much! Glad it was only partially my own incompetence!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't think it is your fault in this instance, it is very odd for the spec to allow multiple ways for a browser to implement behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Moving the padding to a ::before pseudo-element for `.streamRatio` will make it display correctly on Firefox and Edge.

```
.streamRatio::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great fix for this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Inside display:flex, Firefox does not accept percentage padding.**

I added

```
display:table;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
```

and it fixed the problem, although I'm not sure if it comes with another problems. I couldn't see any problem after when testing with IE Chrome Safari and Firefox. at least at recent versions.